# Using Pandas, how do I use if/then logic against two columns to fill in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master spreadsheet with the following:

```
ClientID    Region    Number Value
61661       AMER      38150
1212        EMEA      2012
6543        AMER      38800
3115        LA        40121
3119        AMER      1000
```

What I want to do is add a new column to answer the question "For those in the region column with AMER or LA and the Number Value > 31,000, put the word "High" in the new column. Otherwise, if the region is AMER or LA and it's less than 31,000, put "Low". So, the new spreadsheet should look like this:

```
ClientID    Region    Number Value  New Column  
61661       AMER      38150         High
1212        EMEA      2012          
6543        AMER      38800         High
3115        LA        40121         High
3119        AMER      1000          Low
```

I took a look at https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions.html to get somewhat of an idea of how to do this, I tried the following:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('Check.xlsx')
Master = df.parse('Clients')
HighNumber= Master['Number Value'] > 31000
region=(Master['Region']=='AMER') | (Master['Region']=='LA')

Master['New Column']= Master[HighNumber & region]
```

but I'm getting

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 20, placement implies 1
```

I think it has something to do with me not asking it to loop through the whole dataframe to give me the values, but I'm not entirely sure. Any pointers would be fantastic!

Comment: At the least, I would expect this to be a mistake:`region=(Master['Region']=='AMER') | (Master['Region']=='LA')`

Comment: Good call @Henry, edited above. Thank you! :)

Comment: What you put is different to what I put. Your logical check there will always resolve true, because `| 'LA'` is always `True` - i.e. what it is doing is checking `OR is 'LA' an object'` which is `True` because a dynamically created string is `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use nested `np.where`

```
import numpy as np

isin = df.Region.isin(['AMER', 'LA'])
nv = df['Number Value'] > 31000

df['New Column'] = np.where(isin & nv, 'High', np.where(isin & ~nv, 'Low', ''))

print(df)

   ClientID Region  Number Value New Column
0     61661   AMER         38150       High
1      1212   EMEA          2012           
2      6543   AMER         38800       High
3      3115     LA         40121       High
4      3119   AMER          1000        Low
```

We can improve performance by utilizing the underlying numpy arrays

```
isin = df.Region.isin(['AMER', 'LA']).values
nv = df['Number Value'].values > 31000

df['New Column'] = np.where(isin & nv, 'High', np.where(isin & ~nv, 'Low', ''))
```

***timing***

[image]

***response to comments***

```
isin = df.Region.isin(['AMER', 'LA']).values
nv = df['Number Value'].values > 31000
em = df.Region.values == 'EMEA'

df['New Column'] = np.where(
    isin & nv, 'High',
    np.where(
        isin & ~nv, 'Low',
        np.where(em, 'See SS 2', '')
    ))

   ClientID Region  Number Value New Column
0     61661   AMER         38150       High
1      1212   EMEA          2012   See SS 2
2      6543   AMER         38800       High
3      3115     LA         40121       High
4      3119   AMER          1000        Low
```

Comment: np doesn't seem to exist? Is that a different library I should be using?

Comment: @user3097421 apologies.  That is numpy and is included when you import pandas.  You can access it via `pd.np`.  However, we very often import it directly `import numpy as np`.  We also leave it out in our answers because we get sloppy.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Sorry, I'm SUPER new to this! Now if I wanted to add a third thing and say anyone with EMEA under 5000 gets the word "See Spreadsheet 2", would I just add a new variable similar to nv?

Comment: @user3097421 see updated post.  You add another `np.where`